# fetch sub-string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

`string subject = "Re: Customer request [#11#]";`

I want to fetch **[#11#]** from the above string. At run time instead of 11 there can be any number e.g. 12,13,14 etc.

Please suggest me appropriate Regex to fetch this output.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this: `\[#\d{0,}#\]`

You can fiddle with it on https://regex101.com/r/uA8fX9/3